# Sound not working with an SB Audigy card

Tags: sound

I got no sound on 12.04 - it's an amd64 desktop with SB Audigy card that has worked in all previous incarnations of Ubuntu

I have tried alsa mixer and sound settings. All volume is up and all mutes are off.

I tried installing alsa drive modules and got this:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-alsa-driver-modules-3.2.0-25-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-alsa-driver-modules-3.2.0-25-generic'
```

Comment: have you tried toying around in the sound preferences that came with ubuntu.
often its that you have selected either the wrong output or the wrong mode.

Comment: I have the same problems. I've always had problems with sound. In the past, the only Distro that worked was SUSE. I use a Creative Live1024 card. I've tried every mode and combination I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same promblem with Ubuntu 10.10; also sound issues with skype, to fix the problem I was told to use pulseaudio as a set audio-mixer,and leave the stereo volume one speaker at 90% and the other at 10%, and solved, until today works fine. Cheers.

Comment: Can you provide more detailed instructions? How do I know if I'm using pulseaudio?

Comment: Hi osfast: Yep I have fiddled with these. There are far fewer options than on the previous versions of Ubuntu: On output i only get "Digital Output, Analog output/No amplifier, Analog output/Amplifier and Dummy output". None of these are muted, and the volume slider is at 100%. Test Sound gives nada. Strangely on the input, when I tap the mic, there is a response on the input level meter, but no sound. When I run Audigy or JACK Rack, they show no option for routing to a system output. obviously none of the players work either. Can I test to see if the hardware has died?